# Not waiving the right to see letter of recommendation

Tags: graduate-school, recommendation-letter

I would like to know is it bad and unethical if I do not waive my right to see the letter of recommendation written by the professors?

Should I talk to the professor before to see whether they are OK with that?

Comment: Tiny point of information: you _waive_ a right; you _wave_ a magic wand. (I edited.)